# Substract two times and display the result in third textbox automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

Textbox3 shows the start time of a procedure and TextBox4 shows the end time of the same procedure. I would like it if the textboxes were in a 12 hour clock showing an am/pm tag on the textbox's. Then in Textbox2 it would show the differance between Textbox3 and Textbox4 in Hours and Minutes.

**For Example:**

```
In Time: 9:00 AM
Out Time : 6:00 PM
```

**Then result will display here**

```
Approx Time : 9
```

If input is like this

```
In Time: 9:00 AM
Out time: 6.05 PM
```

Then result should

```
Approx Time: 9:05
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

JavaScript code:

```
    function calculateTime() {

        var valuestart = $("[id$=TextBox3]").pickatime({ interval: 1 }).val();
        var valuestop = $("[id$=TextBox4]").pickatime({ interval: 1 }).val();


        var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestart);
        var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestop);

        var difference = timeEnd - timeStart;
        var diff_result = new Date(difference);

        var hourDiff = diff_result.getHours();

        document.getElementById("TextBox2").innerHTML = hourDiff;        

   }
    $("select").change(calculateTime);
    calculateTime();
```

I tried this above code but unable to get the result. I am new in JavaScript. So please help me to do so.

Getting this error,

Error Image

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Show your attempts. SO is not a place where you can dump requirements and get complete code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: SO is for solving specific problems, not making others to code for you.

Comment: Instead of `var hourDiff = diff_result.getHours();` try `timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours()`. Also if you are using jQuery, keep DOM access constant. Either `$()` or `document.`

Comment: @Rajesh Have used your suggestion but not working still

Comment: @Kusum this: `timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours()` is your HourDiff. You do not have to set to some date object.

Comment: Your problem is: you don't have an html element with id `TextBox2` because [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return `null` when no such element exists in the DOM. And `null` doesn't have an innerHtml property.

Comment: text box have value attribute, like this document.getElementById('txt1').value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I edited my answer, because the previous one was inefficient.**

To get the difference between `In Time` and `Out Time`, do as instructed below:

**First**, let's get the values of the `In Time` and `Out Time` textboxes:

```
// Declare the variables
var valuestart = document.getElementById("in-time-textbox").value,
    valuestop = document.getElementById("in-time-textbox").value;

/* I left it the same as you had it */
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestart),
    timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestop);
```

- I don't use jQuery, so the `pickatime()` method you use is not available to me.
- So instead, I will just assume that the values are typed inside their respective textboxes as in a normal textbox.

---

**Then**, let's go on with the calculation:

```
/* Determine the value of the variable via a conditional ternary operator */
var hourDiff = (((timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours()) > 0) ?
               (timeEnd - timeStart) / 3600000 + " Hours" :
               (((timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes()) > 0) ?
               (timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes()) + " Minutes" :
               (timeEnd.getSeconds() - timeStart.getSeconds()) + " Seconds"));

/* Alternatively, you can do this with an If/Else if/Else statement */
if ((timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours()) > 0) {
    hourDiff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 3600000 + " Hours";  // 1 Hour = 3.6 * 10^6 ms
}
else if ((timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes()) > 0) {
    hourDiff = (timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes()) + " Minutes";
}
else {
    hourDiff = (timeEnd.getSeconds() - timeStart.getSeconds()) + " Seconds";
}
```

- When it comes to setting variables based on different conditions I prefer to use the `ternary operator` since it is more succinct.
- I have also included an `if/else if/else` version in case you are not familiar with it.

---

**Finally**, we can output the result:

```
// Output the result
document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = hourDiff; /* I left the ID the same */
```

---

### CodePen:

I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angelpolitis/pen/kXoGPY) for a better, more visual representation of it working as wanted.

Comment: I think that input text elements need to set their "value" instead of their "innerHTML". May I copy your code and present a fully-working answer?

Comment: @Kusum check out my updated answer. It will guide you step by step and I have also included a codepen for you to see and test.

Answer (score 0):

It's too difficult, if you don't provide the code you tried. Let's say you have 3 textboxes with id's `txt1`, `txt2` and `txt3` respectively. `txt3` is the one where we will output the result.

In case of normal numbers you can use the following function for the `onclick` event of some button.

```
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);

    if(!isNaN(result)){
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
    }
}
```

If the second field contains a date you can use the following code to get the difference in hours. If you want the number of dates again divide it by 24.

```
  var resultInHours = Math.abs(txtFirstNumberValue - txtsecondNumberValue ) / 36e5;
```

Comment: 1. Improve naming convention. 2. You can not directly perform arithmetic operation on time value(hh:mm).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function calculateTime() {

    var valuestart = $("[id$=TextBox3]").pickatime({ interval: 1 }).val();
    var valuestop = $("[id$=TextBox4]").pickatime({ interval: 1 }).val();


    var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestart);
    var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2010 " + valuestop);

    var difference = timeEnd - timeStart;
    var diff_result = new Date(difference);

    var hourDiff = diff_result.getHours();

    document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = hourDiff;        

}

$("select").change(calculateTime);
calculateTime();
```